# How to use GRG NON LINEAR in python?

Tags: python, excel, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

My project's goal is to transcribe excel grg solver method to python.

There you go some context about our variables, and final table building:

```
nb = list(df["B1_NB"]) # list with B1_NB values (its given, not calculated)
sfreal=list(df["B1_Sf"]) # list with B1_sf values (its given, not calculated)
```

```
sf=[b1_nb[0]] #first value of our calculated list sfg1=[abs(b[0]-sf[0])]
 #first value of our calculated list g1
```

```
for i in range(1,12):
    sf.append(sf[-1]+(-x1sf[-1])+(-x2sf[-1])+(-x3sf[-1])+(-x4sf[-1])+(nb[i])) # list to calcule sf, using previous calculated sf
    gap1=abs(sf[i]-sfreal[i])
    g1.append(gap1)
```

```
average1=(sum(g1[0:4]))/4
average2=2.5*(sum(g1[4:7])/3)
average3=5*(sum(g1[7:10])/3)
average4=10*(sum(g1[10:12])/2)
erro_opt=average1+average2+average3+average4
```

Our goal is to find solutions to x1 x2 x3 and x4, that allows to minimize the error_opt.

I used spicy for that, but the result obtained, gave an erro_opt twice as large as excel solver.

I think that it can be because in spicy there is not any GRG algorithm to use, i searched about it and i didn't find any algorithm similar with GRG Non Linear.

Do you know any solution in python similar to GRG (excel solver to non linear problem)?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can purchase GRG for use outside of Excel from solver.com.

Comment: Frontline produce the Solver.